# In iPhone Configuration Utility error while exporting Configuration Profile

Tags: iphone, mac, apple-configurator

I create a Configuration Profile for VPN in iPhone Configuration Utility but when i try to export that profile i get error on console

```
*** -[__NSPlaceHolderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from object[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem by myself.
What i was doing wrong is select sign the profile but i don't have any certificate installed to sign it. So i just select None from drop down menu and the problem has gone.